# Add vertical line to a pgfplots histogram

Tags: histogram, pgfplots

How do I add a vertical line between the bars in a histogram?

The following constructs my diagram:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5},
    xtick=data, ymin=0, bar width=30pt]
  \addplot[ybar,fill=lightgray] coordinates {
    (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,5) (5,3) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of this code]

How do I place a vertical line between (for example), the 3rd and 4th column?

I've tried `\draw (3.5,0) -- (3.5,5);`, but this doesn't work.  It looks like getting hold of specific points in the diagram is complicated (something to do with `axis cs`?) but I've not managed to make any sense of any examples nor find the place in the 500-page manual.

Comment: Add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble, and coordinates are interpreted as axis coordinates by default. Or do e.g. `(axis cs:3.5, 0)`

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but that doesn't work for me.  I get:

`! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate '3.5' has not been defined with 'symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5}... Maybe it has been misspelled? Or did you mean something like [normalized]3.5?.`

Comment: Oops, sorry, my mistake. I didn't see the symbolic coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
If you really have 1,2,... as ticklabels, you can just remove the symbolic coordinates and use axis cs:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, %symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5},
    xtick=data, ymin=0, bar width=30pt]
  \addplot[ybar,fill=lightgray] coordinates {
    (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,5) (5,3) };
\draw (axis cs:3.5,0) -- (axis cs:3.5,5.5);,
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Or add compat=11 (or higher) and don't use axis cs:
\begin{center}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} % normally add this to preamble
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, %symbolic x coords={1,2,3,4,5},
    xtick=data, ymin=0, bar width=30pt]
  \addplot[ybar,fill=lightgray] coordinates {
    (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,5) (5,3) };
\draw (3.5,0) -- (3.5,5.5);,
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

If you have non-numeric ticklabels, use xticklabels instead of symbolic coordinates:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, xticklabels={foo,bar,baz,baa,abc},
    xtick=data, ymin=0, bar width=30pt]
  \addplot[ybar,fill=lightgray] coordinates {
    (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,5) (5,3) };
\draw (axis cs:3.5,0) -- (axis cs:3.5,5.5);,
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

Instead of manually specifying a y-coordinate you can access the value used in the axis with pgfkeysvalueof:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar stacked, xticklabels={foo,bar,baz,baa,abc},
    xtick=data, ymin=0, bar width=30pt]
  \addplot[ybar,fill=lightgray] coordinates {
    (1,3) (2,2) (3,1) (4,5) (5,3) };
\draw (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- (axis cs:3.5,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});,
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: (Not the best answer, sorry, dinnertime.)

Comment: Thanks - that's good enough to produce what I need.